# React App running from mapped network drive

Tags: node.js, reactjs, windows, hot-reload

I've just inherited a React node project and have the code hosted on our network. I have noticed that hot reloading is not working when loading the source from a network drive (which has been mapped on my local machine). I have tested running it from a local drive and hot reload does work, so it appears as though there may be a permission issue reading from a network drive.

Running in a windows environment.

Surely there is a way to run code from the network rather than my local machine? I do not want each developer to have to maintain their own local copies of the code.

Comment: Everyone having their own copies would make the most sense. (1) An individual wouldn't be able to break everyone else's work (2) A bug introduced by one person wouldn't then interfere with everyone else, some of whom may be working on something related (3) Better for one person running the app to have no possibility of changing something on the network drive and causing unexpected changes for others (eg, file changes due to compilation). Everyone should really have their own copy of the repo, and then merge with Git (maybe with Git hooks to automate things).

Comment: There's almost certainly a way around the permission issue, but that whole approach is pretty suspicious.

Comment: @CertainPerformance we run sourcesafe in house to avoid conflicts. I feel much safer having code on a server which is much more robust and has a better backup solution than a local PC.

Comment: If backups are what you're worried about, put the git repo somewhere. If that's on your network (somewhere safe), that'd be a good option - and then there'd be no issue with people running the code completely locally, and checking in changes when desired.